# dns timeouts - resolv.conf wrong?

Tags: timeout, dns, debian, resolve, nameservers

i have a question concerning the correct setup of debian's resolv.conf file.

i have 3 domains:
    a-domain.com,
    b-domain.com and 
    c-domain.com

the server has a static IP.

do i have to add all (one by one) domains to resolv.conf ?
currently none of them are in resolv.conf - i have sth. like 
dns timeouts - the page is only available after 10-20 seconds!
same issue for ssh.

what did i forget or what is misconfigured ?

thanks for hints in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

They go in /etc/hosts like so:

```
192.168.0.1 a-domain.com
192.168.0.2 b-domain.com
192.168.0.3 c-domain.com
```

(Use the actual IP addresses, of course. And I'm assuming this is on a private subnet -- otherwise why aren't you using DNS?)

resolv.conf is there to set up your DNS servers.

Comment: i use dnsmadeeasy.com as nameserver, the IP is a static IP (globally available) and is registred. the pointing of (a|b|c)-domain.com to the IP works if i use nslookup i get 

 nslookup a-domain.com
;; Got recursion not available from 10.X.X.X trying next server
Server:  10.X.X.Y
Address: 10.X.X.Y#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: a-domain.com
Address: X.X.X.X

the IP (Address: X.X.X.X ) is correct!